# Securely distributing passwords and salts that will be derived by client programs

Tags: passwords, key

I am creating a client-server architecture running on top of the KCP protocol in Go. The package for KCP that I'm using is KCP-Go (https://github.com/xtaci/kcp-go). The package supports packet-level encryption and FEC. To use the packet-level encryption feature, I need to generate an AES key. Following the latest OWASP recommendations for securely storing passwords and keys, this is what I've done thus far:

- I have generated a 64-byte password and salt.
- I pass that to PBKDF2, using (600000 * num_cpus) rounds, and requesting a 32-byte key.

Now I am wondering how to exactly securely distribute this key. At this time, I start up another TCP server and allow clients to connect. When they do, I send them the password, salt, number of iterations, and checksum hashes for those three to ensure they're not tampered with, and allow the client to perform key derivation. My question is: Is this method of distribution actually secure, or should I find some other way (i.e. using public keys)? If there is a more secure method to allow clients and the server to communicate, what should I do instead?
I should note that when clients and servers send messages to one another a hash of the message is included along with the message to allow clients to verify the messages validity (I'm using SHAKE256). The hash funciton used during key derivation is BLAKE2B (though I have thought about using Argon2).

Comment: You'll probably want to use public key cryptography to authenticate and DH key exchange or similar to actually share the keys.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you mean that I should keep KCP, but generate a public and private keypair on startup, then on the secondary port, set up DH/ECDH and exchange the key that way?

Comment: Yes, since it doesn't look like KCP will handle all the key generation for you, you will probably want to combine it with PKI and some key exchange to securely establish the session keys. Unless I'm missing something, it doesn't seem like KCP allows you to use certificates or similar for authenticating clients and servers.

Comment: It wouldn't be too hard for me to remove KCP and replace it with something like (say) WebSockets. I might go that route instead; at least then I have certificate authentication and TLS right out of the box. I'm not even really sure why KCP doesn't support PKI or TLS certificates; its such a common technology in this modern day and age...

Comment: Yep, going with WebSockets. I'm not sure if I should define tis as an answer or not since its not really an "answer" under the usual definition of an answer. Thanks for the help! :)